# Sorting a large datasst of integers distributed over multiple machines

Tags: sorting, parallel-processing, distributed

Assume we have a large dataset of integers distributed over multiple nodes on a cluster. What is the best way to sort these numbers?  We are not concerned about the hardware, assuming we have enough resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more search, I found that the solution is an algorithm called "Merging networks" drived from "bitonic sort algo". That solved my problem.

Comment: "merging networks" aka "bitonic sort algorithm" aka "sorting networks" normally refer to hardware parallel sorting methods, not how to merge a dataset split across nodes. The nodes each sort their own part of the dataset first, then the nodes have to merge the sorted parts into a single sorted dataset using the network connnecting the nodes. Assuming n nodes, the process starts off with n sorted sub-arrays, which requires n/2 merge operations to end up with n/2 sorted sub-arrays twice the size and so, same as a bottom up merge sort. Bandwidth can be an issue.

Comment: For integers, a radix sort could be used. For example if there are 16 nodes, the upper 4 bits of each integer would indicate which node it should go to.  The question doesn't state the initial state of the dataset (is it all on one node?), but the dataset would be processed to create groups of integers based on the most significant "digit", and send each group of integers to the proper node. Each node would then do a radix sort on it's part, then the parts would be physically or logically concatenated to create a sorted array of integers.